# Git & Eclipse: Handle user-specfic project files

Tags: eclipse, git

I have a general question regarding project and classfile handling in git:

Of course, a solution should be applicable to different kind of projects with specific environment files not necessary for the raw build-process but only for setting the user environment:

Having x projects that interact in a eclipse workspace. Each of these projects has a .classpath and a .project file as well as a .settings folder.

Now, I want to make sure that there is a inital "raw"-version of these files in the repo that have to be adapted of the users working with this repository and make sure, that these files are not commited due to this environment-specific modification process.

Can I avoid this? Is there a kind of flag in git, indicating that the file's modifications are ignored in the future?

.gitignore are no valid option in this case, since files that are included in this file aren't ignored if they are initially commited.

Comment: I don't know if what you are looking for is possible. However, I am curious to know why you are looking for this solution. To me, it appears kind of a non-sense, since the first import of the project will generate appropriate .project and other eclipse-related file. Moreover, the raw-files could break your developer environment if they are non compatible (or will be overwritten, not sure actually). Maybe you have some special case?

Answer (score 2):

To my mind that's not possible. But there is a simple alternative: Do not provide the initial version as a file in the git repository, but have it be created by a script or copied from another location (which itself might be in your repository again). Then you can gitignore your files from the very start.

E.g. a very simple solution would be to add an [Ant builder](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm) to the list of builders of your project. That Ant script could look at your settings files and copy them from some shared location, modify them in place or do any other magic things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to [Lock](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/locking.html)
a file. Check out the link and let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: it looks good but I don't want to use gitolite for this action, isn't there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [`git update-index --assume-unchanged`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) which will ignore those files when commiting.

Careful though, if they're changed somewhere else (e.g. by someone who did not `assume-unchanged` them):

> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the
>   index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the
>   assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle
>   the situation manually.

Given the type of files you want to apply it to, it might not be that often (e.g. when you update a project classpath, which should be quite seldom...), so users (or a script in the repo) can take care of it themselves.